# What's the equivalent of Android's "ClickableSpan" class in Swift/Objective-C?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uitextview

So I'm trying to create a view where part of the entered text becomes a link to another UIView. I was searching a lot and found the ClickableSpan class that enabled to click on part of the text. It's like in Instagram where when a user types @username or #hashtag it creates a link to another view. I'm just wondering how to give an action to a portion of a text. The text can be in either UILabel or UITextView. Do I use AttributedString, or what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that for `UITextView` by using the `dataDetectorTypes` property.

Objective-C:

```
self.textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Swift

```
textview.dataDetectorTypes = .Link
```